# Problems while loading configuration files in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having some problems while loading a configuration file in YAML. I have added the following code in my `application.rb` file.

```
AppConfig.setup do |config|
    config[:env] = Rails.env
    config[:uri] = "yaml://#{Rails.root}/config/app_config.yml"
end
```

But when I try to run the server, it shows the following error.

> bad URI(is not URI?): yaml:///path_to_project/config/app_config.yml (URI::InvalidURIError)

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I use the stable solution on production last 2 years called [configatron](https://github.com/markbates/configatron/)

Comment: it takes YAML files even with ERB, then parse it and provide Singleton class with your configuration depends on current Rails environment. the class accessible from anywhere of an application

Comment: Actually I have been using app_config gem and following the wiki at http://oshuma.github.com/app_config/. It was supposed to work but in my case it's showing the above error